# Querying inside of a for loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am wondering if there is a way to do what I am doing more efficiently. Right now, I have a class that retrives statuses from the database. It's pretty simple and shouldn't really effect performance all that much.

```
public function get ($var1, $var2, $var3)
{
    $feed = array(); //Initialize an empty array
    //Query the database
    $Statement = $this->Database->prepare("SELECT id, name, excerpt, post, timestamp, tags, title FROM posts WHERE col1 = ? AND col2 = ? AND col3 = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15");
    $Statement->execute(array($var1, $var2, $var3));

    while($row = $Statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $posts[] = array( "id" => $row["id"], /*etc...*/ ); 
    }

    return $posts;
} //end get
```

And then my page set up something like this which I know is not efficient at all:

```
<?php for ($count = 1; $count <= $total; $count++): //Display the calendar      
    echo $count;            
    $feed = $Feed->get($count, $total, $var3);

    foreach ($feed as $post): 
        echo $post["id"];           
    endforeach; 
endfor; ?>
```

I hope that makes sense. There's a lot more html thrown in there and everything. Right now there are only 18 rows in my database, and it takes 10 seconds to load the page. Which is really bad. I have to set it up this way because of the design of the site. So the foreach loop has to be within the for loop because the whole thing is set up as a calendar.

My question is whether it would be more efficient to select all of the rows, save them outside of the for loop and then work with that array, or whether it's better to run each query inside the foreach loop the way I'm doing it now (i've read a lot, and know that most people say this is a huge no no). And what kind of issues would I run into if I used the former option and there were say a million rows in the database.

I hope that makes sense. I'll update the question if it doesn't. Right now though about 30 queries are being made to only access 1 or 2 rows. But the only other option I could come up with is selecting all of the rows in the table, and then working with that array, but if there are pretend 1 million rows in the db, I feel like that would affect performance a lot more.

Am I right, and what are some solutions? Thanks

Comment: Not an answer, but may I just mention how nice it is to (for once) have someone use PDO (with prepared statements) instead of `mysql_*`.

Comment: Generally it is better to limit the amount of queries to a db. Each DB interaction takes crucial milliseconds... but you also have to balance that against the amount of stray data you will be passing through your socket in order to have a more generalized query. Also +1 for using PDO (and +1 to the PDO comment too :P)

Comment: @Dave what would you say is a limit to the amount of stray data I'd be saving in an array. Because I could select all posts from a months time, and I think that's what I'm going to do, but at what poist would that option kind of fail me vs. querying exactly what I need for each day. So what's the tipping point of too many queries vs. too much stray data? and thanks h2ooooo

Comment: The tipping point is really going server/setup dependent. I tend to get better benchmarks when I use a broad enough query to pull the data into an array and work with it inside of the program. The benchmarks will change drastically depending on if you are working with a local or remote db server. It would also be dependent on where your resource bottlenecks are (my servers tend to be CPU bound, but have plenty of memory and IO for local data manipulation). Keep in mind that each db query traverses your entire db in search of your specific conditions, multiply that by query count and it adds up

Comment: Thanks @Dave! I changed up the way I'm fetching data and the results are weird. I'm posting another question about it I hope you are able to check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to point out that I did resolve the issue. If anyone is wondering why the foreach loop was querying so sow it was because I accidentally deleted a line where I connected to the Facebook api within the foreach loop every time to gather the poster's information. So if anyone ever stumbles upon this question, just to be sure I want to clarify that making many facebook->api calls is a bad thing. save the info in your database and query that instead.